# How to use open Id in jsp

Tags: struts2

Hi I am trying to build a login system like Stack Overflow but not find the right way to do this in JSP. I am working in struts2.

Answer (score 3):

The following illustrate Single Sign On (SSO) using Oauth, for which you can create a SSO system similar to that of Stack Overflow.

Use scribe: https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/getting-started

The following example will demonstrate using Twitter...

1) Demonstrate an action to get twitter credentials.

```
package com.quaternion.struts2basic.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Results;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
import org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder;
import org.scribe.builder.api.TwitterApi;
import org.scribe.model.Token;
import org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService;

@Results(value = {
    @Result(name = "success", location = "${authorizationURL}", type = "redirect"),
    @Result(name = "error", location = "/WEB-INF/content/error.jsp")
})
public class TwitterGrantAccess extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {

    private Map<String, Object> session;
    private String authorizationURL = null;

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        //Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        String consumer_key = "rUPV8tpIcFtyMeSDlnzclA";
        String consumer_secret = "16omdjNoEYgwoXfZMc0XrXSxiHDaS0UZUxQzWhTFg";

        OAuthService twitterService = new ServiceBuilder()
                .provider(TwitterApi.class)
                .apiKey(consumer_key)
                .apiSecret(consumer_secret)
                .callback("http://127.0.0.1:8080/Struts2Basic/twitter-callback")
                .build();
        Token requestToken = twitterService.getRequestToken();
        authorizationURL = twitterService.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
        session.put("twitterService", twitterService);
        session.put("requestToken", requestToken);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getAuthorizationURL() {
        return this.authorizationURL;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) {
        this.session = map;
    }
}
```

2) Action which twitter redirects back to...

```
package com.quaternion.struts2basic.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Results;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
import org.scribe.model.Token;
import org.scribe.model.Verifier;
import org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService;

@Results(value = {
    @Result(name = "success", location = "/WEB-INF/content/twitter-callback-success.jsp"),
    @Result(name = "error", location = "/WEB-INF/content/error.jsp")
})
public class TwitterCallback extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {

    private Map<String, Object> session;
    private String key;
    private String secret;
    //returned from twitter
    private String oauth_token;
    private String oauth_verifier;

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        if (session.containsKey("accessToken") && session.get("accessToken") != null) {
            return SUCCESS; //accessToken already exists!
        }
        Token requestToken = (Token) session.get("requestToken");
        if (requestToken == null) {
            super.addActionError("requestToken is null");
            return ERROR;
        }
        OAuthService twitterService = (OAuthService) session.get("twitterService");
        System.out.println(requestToken.toString());
        System.out.println(this.getOauth_verifier());
        //Token accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, this.getOauth_verifier());
        Token accessToken = twitterService.getAccessToken(requestToken, new Verifier(this.getOauth_verifier()));
        session.put("accessToken", accessToken);
        this.setKey(accessToken.getToken()); //just to see something happen
        this.setSecret(accessToken.getSecret());//just to see something happen
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) {
        this.session = map;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getSecret() {
        return secret;
    }

    public void setSecret(String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }

    public String getOauth_token() {
        return oauth_token;
    }

    public void setOauth_token(String oauth_token) {
        this.oauth_token = oauth_token;
    }

    public String getOauth_verifier() {
        return oauth_verifier;
    }

    public void setOauth_verifier(String oauth_verifier) {
        this.oauth_verifier = oauth_verifier;
    }
}
```

I'll omit the views because they really don't do anything

3) An action which writes "Hello from Struts2!", which isn't very good because twitter will only let you run this once and because the status is the same will not let you post it again... but it gets the process across. After updating the status it redirects to your twitter page, if you change the "YOUR_USER_NAME" part of the url in the redirect of course.

```
package com.quaternion.struts2basic.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Results;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
import org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest;
import org.scribe.model.Response;
import org.scribe.model.Token;
import org.scribe.model.Verb;
import org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService;

@Results({
    @Result(name = "success", location = "https://twitter.com/#!/YOUR_USER_NAME", type = "redirect")
})
public class Tweet extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {

    private Map<String, Object> session;
    private String status;

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        Token accessToken = (Token) session.get("accessToken");
        OAuthService twitterService = (OAuthService) session.get("twitterService");
        String url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json?status=";
        String twitterStatus = "hello!";
        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, url + twitterStatus);
        twitterService.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        Response response = request.send();
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) {
        session = map;
    }
}
```

That is pretty much it.  The nice things about scribe is it is so easy to configure for the different providers (for basic authentication, using their APIs after is another matter and that is up to you).

Comment: scribe use Oauth and not openId i believe. i am using scribe in all my applications :)

Comment: I don't use OpenId I mistakenly thought that OpenId was simply another identity provider which used Oauth, very much my mistake... however the OP wants a way to do SSO and may not be entirely committed to OpenId... So I'll readdress the answer as a SSO method using Oauth, maybe someone will find use in it.

Comment: +1 nice example. I just went for OpenId since OP asked for something like Stack-overflow which use open-id system :)thanks for the really good example

Answer (score 1):

It dependents upon how you want to build it.There are certain number of library which you can use to build you login system and few of them are

1. [Joid](http://code.google.com/p/joid/)
2. [openid4java](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/)

Here is a outline what all you have to do in order to make the complete flow

1. Create a JSP page where use can select a way to choose his login system.
2. Call an action class which Create an authentication request for this identifier.
3. Redirect user to the OpenId service provider and let him authorize themself.
4. Receive the OpenID Provider's authentication response at your callback action.
5. parse the response if you need to store some information.